# Finding Momentum in Parabolic Polar Coordinates

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism

The problem I am doing necessitates the use of finding the momentum in parabolic polar coordinates.  I need to transform the following Hamiltonian from cartesian to parabolic polar coordinates.

$H=\frac{1}{2}(p_x^2+p_y^2+p_z^2)+\frac{\alpha}{r}+Pz$

The coordinate transformation is...

$x=\zeta\eta\cos\phi$

$y=\zeta\eta\sin\phi$

$z=\frac{1}{2}(\zeta^2-\eta^2)$

So the first thing I did was find the generating function.
Start with x,
$x=-\frac{\partial F}{\partial p_x}=\zeta\eta\cos\phi \rightarrow F=-\zeta\eta p_x \cos\phi+f(p_y,p_z,\zeta,\eta,\phi)$

Then plug in expression for y,

$y=-\frac{\partial F}{\partial p_y}=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_y}=\zeta\eta\sin\phi \rightarrow f(p_y,p_z,\zeta,\eta,\phi)=-\zeta \eta p_y \sin \phi + g(p_z,\zeta,\eta,\phi)$

Now plug in for z expression,

$z=-\frac{\partial F}{\partial p_z}=-\frac{\partial g}{\partial p_z}=\frac{1}{2}(\zeta^2-\eta^2) \rightarrow g(p_z,\zeta,\eta,\phi)=-\frac{1}{2}p_z(\zeta^2-\eta^2) + h(\zeta,\eta,\phi)$

The function $h$ is arbitrary and can be set to zero.  Thus the total generating function is the following.

$F=-\zeta \eta p_x \cos \phi - \zeta \eta p_y \sin\phi-\frac{1}{2}p_z(\zeta^2-\eta^2)$

Thus, the momentum in parabolic coordinates are given be these three expressions.

$p_{\zeta}=-\frac{\partial F}{\partial \zeta}=\eta p_x\cos\phi +\eta p_y\sin\phi+zp_z$

$p_{\eta}=-\frac{\partial F}{\partial \eta}=\zeta p_x \cos \phi+\zeta p_y \sin\phi-\eta p_z$

$p_{\phi}=-\frac{\partial F}{\partial \phi}=-\zeta \eta p_x \sin \phi +\zeta \eta p_y \cos\phi$

So now it seems like the only thing left to do is to solve for $p_x,p_y$ and $p_z$ and then plug into the Hamiltonian to get the transformed version.  This is easy enough for $p_z$, I simply multiply the first equation by $\zeta$ and the second equation by $\eta$ and subtract the two and get the following.

$p_z=\frac{p_{\zeta}-p_{\eta}}{\zeta^2+\eta^2}$

The issue comes in for solving $p_x$ and $p_y$.  I am getting very long complicated expressions, and then I would need to square these expressions when plugging in!  It makes me think like I made a mistake with the initial equations.  What do you guys think? Am I doing this correctly? Did I make a mistake somewhere? I checked it over several times already.  Maybe I need to take a break and come back to this later!

Comment: Way too much work, unless you really want some in depth practice in curvilinear coordinates (good thing, actually!). Otherwise, take a look at Eq. 15 in this paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.205.4605&rep=rep1&type=pdf (Penn State link). See Wikipedia for the scale factors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_coordinates#Three-dimensional_scale_factors

Comment: I will read this stuff over, but we did an example in class using the method I am doing and didn't mention anything about scale factors so I assume I am supposed to do it the long way :(

(It was the same problem, except using confocal elliptical coordinates)